# Colleagues get error 5 in Excel-file with VBA, but same file works fine on my computer?

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, excel-2013

We have an Excel-file with a large amount of VBA behind it. The Excel-file works just fine on my computer, but so far 3 of my colleagues (non-IT'ers) have gotten this error:

> Runtime error 5: 
>   Invalid procedure call or argument

The error is located on this line, and I don't see why it is throwing an error there because it's just a simple Set (and it works perfectly fine on my computer):

```
Set MyButton = Application.CommandBars("Attributions").Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Before:=10)
```

We all have the exact same Excel-file. I even sent them my version of the file, in which everything is running fine and no errors happen, but even when they open my version of the file they still get the above error on the above line!

What exactly could cause this? We all have `Office 2013` and updates are installed automatically. The problem started about 2 weeks ago with one colleague and since this week I heard from two other colleagues that they have the same problem. One even said it suddenly worked again after he moved to a different desk (which I doubt would have an influence) but shortly after, it started getting the error again.
I have absolutely no idea why they get the error, or what might cause it. Seeing as we now all have the same version and they still get the error, I am thinking it might have something to do with Excel itself but that's just my idea.
Does this sound familiar to anyone here? Or does anyone know what might cause this, and how it can be fixed?
Edit: a while ago I checked on my colleagues their computers to see if the CommandBar was present, and it was. Even then the error still happened.

Comment: Does the workbook create that commandbar - it's not a standard one, and an error 5 would suggest it doesn't exist.

Comment: please, check references in VBA project, go to IDE >> menu >> Tools >> References... Are there any `missing:...` items on the list?

Comment: Rory, it does create that commandbar. KazJaw, I don't see "missing:..." anywhere in the list so I suppose the references are set correctly.

Comment: Do you use any activex controls on worksheets in the file?

Comment: To narrow down your investigation, break down the chain: `Dim a, b, MyButton : Set a = Application.CommandBars("Attributions") : Set b = a.Controls : Set MyButton = b.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Before:=10)`  Put each of these on a separate line to figure out where exactly the error is occurring.

Comment: Rory, there are ActiveX elements but I already tried the fix where you have to delete some .exd files. Solved some problems on other Excel-files, but not on this one. Jean-François Corbett, I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: It gave an error on the second line now. But still, I don't understand why since the commandbar exists. I even had another colleague from IT come over to help me check, and a colleague who had the problem was here as well. We compared our settings in Excel, literally every setting I could imagine that might have an influence. My colleague now has the same settings as me and it still gives an error.

Comment: Can you see the menu controls on the AddIns tab?

Comment: I can see them yes, but my colleagues can't.

Comment: Then for whatever reason, the menu is not being created. That's what you need to look into.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a function that checks if there is a `CommandBar` in your `Application` like this:

```
Function IsCommandBarValid(cbName As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    IsCommandBarValid = True
    For i = 1 To Application.CommandBars.Count
        If (Application.CommandBars(i).Name = cbName) Then
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IsCommandBarValid = False
End Function
```

Now, You can use it to see that your user have that `CommandBar` in his or her `Application`, then make it like this:

```
If (Not IsCommandBarValid("Attributions")) Then
    Call Application.CommandBars.Add(Name:="Attributions")
End If
' And after this add your code
Set MyButton = Application.CommandBars("Attributions").Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Before:=10)
```

Comment: The users that have this problem also have the CommandBar in their application. I do not know why the error points to the CommandBar, it is there in their application... Makes no sense. The issue sometimes even disappears and the file works fine, and days later it gives the error again. 
Also, why did you edit my original question? The title makes no sense at all now.

Comment: @Magali you can edit over my edits any time, But usually tags making sense more than title, and edits make a question active for users to see it again, As soon as you want to make sense to users make an edit to your question, But I think If you use my solution you should never have any error ;).

Answer (score -1):

**Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)**

Some part of the call can't be completed. This error has the following causes and solutions:

- An argument probably exceeds the range of permitted values. For example, the Sin function can only accept values within a certain range. Positive arguments less than 2,147,483,648 are accepted, while 2,147,483,648 generates this error.

  > Check the ranges permitted for arguments.
- This error can also occur if an attempt is made to call a procedure that isn't valid on the current platform. For example, some procedures may only be valid for Microsoft Windows, or for the Macintosh, and so on.

  > Check platform-specific information about the procedure.

For additional information, select the item in question and press <kbd>F1</kbd> (in Windows) or <kbd>HELP</kbd> (on the Macintosh).

- [MSDN Source Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264283.aspx)